# Embedding UINavigationController in scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to do an application with 3 startup views, which you can swipe between. Pretty much Snapchat like.

I've got this going pretty well, but when I try to embed one of the 3 View Controller, it gets resized to a small part of the screen.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let accCtrl = AccountViewController()
    let feedCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
    let hashsCtrl = AccountViewController()

    self.addChildViewController(hashsCtrl)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(hashsCtrl.view)
    hashsCtrl.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(feedCtrl)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(feedCtrl.view)
    feedCtrl.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(accCtrl)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(accCtrl.view)
    accCtrl.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    accCtrl.view.frame = view.frame
    // feedCtrl.view.autoresizesSubviews = false
    feedCtrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    feedCtrl.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    feedCtrl.view.setNeedsLayout()
    hashsCtrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width * 2, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.width * 3, view.frame.height)
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(view.frame.width, 0)
}
```

I've noticed that the resulting width of the view on-screen is pretty much x - 280. If I set the feedCtrl.view.frame to a width, the resulting width is 1.0 point. As it is actually - aka the screen width -, it results in a 40.0 point width.

I've also noticed that if I uncomment the line where I put the feedCtrl.view.autoresizeSubviews boolean to false, the width on-screen is correct, but I can't get user-interaction on the view.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In viewDidLoad, try to add (that worked for me):

```
self.ScrollView.frame = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!.frame)!
```